# configure ToggleShowDesktop in Openbox to only act on specified layer

Tags: openbox, lxde

I have a keybinding for `ToggleShowDesktop`. When I press <kbd>Menu</kbd>, all windows get minimized and I see my Desktop Wallpaper (as expected):

```
<keybind key="Menu">
  <action name="ToggleShowDesktop"/>
</keybind>
```

Now the problem is, I don't want to see my wallpaper. I am using `terminator` as my wallpaper, i.e. when I start `terminator`, it is placed on the layer below:

```
<application name="terminator">
  <focus>yes</focus>
  <layer>below</layer>
  <desktop>1</desktop>
  <position>
    <y>0</y>  
    <x>0</x>
  </position> 
  <skip_taskbar>yes</skip_taskbar>
  <maximized>true</maximized>
</application>
```

Is it possible to configure `ToggleShowDesktop` so that it leaves the "below" layer unaffected? i.e. I want only the normal windows to be minimized, but not `terminator`. In other words, I want terminator to behave as normal wallpaper would - be unaffected by `ToggleShowDesktop`.

I am using `Debian Wheezy` with `LXDE`.

## (using method suggested by @Suchipi):

I have left out few details from my original question, and now these details seem to be relevant after all:

My setup has 2 monitors and 4 virtual desktops. So I have "8 wallpapers" to fill with `terminator`. From what I have read previously, I assumed that these 8 windows will have to be distinguishable, so I have created 8 symliks to `terminator`, .i.e.:

```
/usr/bin/terminator-wallpaper-1a  -> terminator
/usr/bin/terminator-wallpaper-1b  -> terminator
/usr/bin/terminator-wallpaper-2a  -> terminator
...
```

In effect created 8 different applications (with different names).

Similarly, in `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` I have not 1, but 8 definitions:

```
<application name="terminator-wallpaper-1a">
  <desktop>1</desktop>
  <position>
    <monitor>1</monitor>
  </position>
  ...
</application>

<application name="terminator-wallpaper-1b">
  <desktop>1</desktop>
  <position> 
    <monitor>2</monitor>
  </position>
  ...
</application>

<application name="terminator-wallpaper-2a">
  <desktop>2</desktop>  
  <position> 
    <monitor>1</monitor>
  </position>
  ...
</application>
```

And lastly, in `/.config/autostart` I have 8 `*.desktop` files, to be started automatically after login:

```
/.config/autostar/terminator-wallpaper-1a.desktop
/.config/autostar/terminator-wallpaper-1b.desktop
/.config/autostar/terminator-wallpaper-2a.desktop
```

This seems to me quiete overcomplicated and inelegant, but I didn't see any better way to do it.

Now, when I follow the instructions from @Suchipi, the following happens:

1) the part with `devilspie` works OK. It turns out, I need only one definition which covers all my 8 windows (substituting `matches` for `is`):

```
$ cat .devilspie/terminator.ds 
(if
(matches (application_name) "terminator-wallpaper")
(begin
(wintype "desktop")
)
)
```

And I can see with `obxprop` that it works as expected.

```
$ obxprop | egrep '(_OB_APP|_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE)'
_OB_APP_TYPE(UTF8_STRING) = "normal"
_OB_APP_TITLE(UTF8_STRING) = "None"
_OB_APP_CLASS(UTF8_STRING) = "Terminator-wallpaper-1"
_OB_APP_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "terminator-wallpaper-1"
_OB_APP_ROLE(UTF8_STRING) = 
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP
```

2) now the part with `xdotool` is more tricky:
 first of all, using `100%` for the resolution does not work, i.e. the window disappears (I don't see it). When using static:

```
xdotool search --class "Terminator-wallpaper-1a" windowunmap --sync windowmap windowsize %1 1920 1056
```

this works for desktop 1 monitor 1. But when I run it for other desktops, it has no effect, i.e.:

```
xdotool search --class "Terminator-wallpaper-2a" windowunmap --sync windowmap windowsize %1 1920 1056
```

Actually, it works for other desktops as well, but only if I run the `xdotool` command on the specific desktop, which I want to affect. i.e. I have to switch to desktop `2` and run `xdotool search --class "Terminator-wallpaper-2a"` and then it works.

Also, I was wondering whether the `windowsize %1` plays any role here.

## UPDATE 2019-12-07:

so, I am now trying to set up same system on Debian Buster (Openbox 3.6) and I am experiencing a new problem. I suspect some property has changed in new version of openbox.

Everything seems to as before, ie:

```
terminator-wallpaper-1a --profile wallpaper -b &
terminator-wallpaper-1b --profile wallpaper -b &
xdotool search --class 'Terminator-wallpaper-1a' windowunmap --sync windowmap windowsize %1 1920 1180 
xdotool search --class 'Terminator-wallpaper-1b' windowunmap --sync windowmap windowsize %1 1920 1180
```

I get two terminals as wallpaper. But the problem is, only one of these terminals is actually usable. The other is "unfocused" and even when I click on it with mouse, I cannot bring it into focus. Ie, I can see the terminal, but I cannot type in it.

This problem did nor exist before, in older Openbox version

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: The Openbox wiki [Action Page](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#ToggleShowDesktop) says that `ToggleShowDesktop` "Hides all windows so that the desktop is visible, and gives focus to the desktop window if one exists (such as in GNOME and KDE)." If you can find out what desktop windows GNOME and KDE have and make terminator have the same properties, I imagine it'd give you the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: The %1 in windowsize is referring to the last selected window, in this case the one that we got with `search --class "terminator"`. See the [xdotool documentation](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) for more information.

Comment: Also, `devilspie` can set the workspace and viewport of a window, as well as controlling maximization. You may want to experiment using `devilspie` to remaximize the window instead of `xdotool`.

Comment: @Suchipi - the window resolution is not the main problem, I can use fixed size. But as I described in my UPDATE, `xdotool` only works for windows which are on the same virtual desktop as the terminal from which I run `xdotool`. Running `xdotool` from a script does not work. But I need to create a script which will autostart and execute `xdotool` upon login. How can I do it?

Comment: `xdotool` can emulate keyboard and mouse input, so maybe you could set it to cycle through your workspaces using keyboard shortcuts and unmap/map the windows as it does so. Refer to the xdotool documentation I linked to above for detailed instructions on how to do this (you'll be using `xdotool key`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Openbox will give the functionality you are looking for to windows whose `_OB_APP_TYPE` property is set to "desktop" (You can use `obxprop` to check the properties of a window).
So we need to set the `_OB_APP_TYPE` for your terminator window to "desktop" so that this will happen.

Reading through the openbox source code, in `client.c` I could see that `_OB_APP_TYPE` is inherited from `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE`. So I looked for an application that could change `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE`. The application I found is called `devilspie`.

First, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

Next, we'll create the folder for `devilspie` configuration files:

```
mkdir ~/.devilspie
```

Now we will add a config file that tells `devilspie` to look for applications named `terminator` and set the window type of them to `desktop`. Put the following into `~/.devilspie/terminator.ds`:

```
(if
(is (application_name) "terminator")
(begin
(wintype "desktop")
)
)
```

Now, if you run `devilspie` (or `devilspie -a` to affect existing windows instead of just newly created ones) you'll notice if you use `obxprop` on terminator that `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` has changed, but `_OB_APP_TYPE` has not yet. Let's use `xdotool` to unmap and remap the window (in X11 terminology this means we will stop drawing and begin drawing the window), which should force openbox to notice the value.

Install xdotool:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then we run the following script to find the `terminator` window, unmap it, wait until it has been unmapped, then remap it. We also resize the window because when it was unmapped and remapped it lost its maximization:

```
xdotool search --class "terminator" windowunmap --sync windowmap windowsize %1 1024 768
```

Replace `1024 768` with your resolution. Also note that newer versions of `xdotool` than those found in Debian's apt repo support using `100% 100%` instead of a static resolution. You can find `.deb` packages for newer versions of `xdotool` at [xdotool's googlecode page.](https://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/downloads/list?can=2&q=label%3adeb+label%3axdotool+label%3afeatured&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount)

The terminator window will immediately become undecorated, and if you now use `obxprop`, you will see that both values have been set properly. If you now press the key you bound `ToggleShowDesktop` to a few times, the terminator window will always stay active.

To make this persistent, you'll want to run these commands on login. The [LXDE Wiki Page for LXSession](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#Automatically_start_some_applications_on_login) shows several different ways to do this (global, per-user, per-profile, etc). Assuming you want these settings just for your user and under the LXDE profile (the default), you'll want to edit `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` and add the commands we ran, keeping in mind that the xdotool command needs to be run after terminator's window has been rendered, so do something like `(sleep 1s & xdotool ...)`. You could also set these commands up as keybinds in openbox if you wish.

Comment: thanks for the detailed instructions. Please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following script which looks like it solves your problems.

```
#!/bin/sh

make_wid_desktop_app() {
    # set the type of the window to 
    xprop -id $1 -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP
    xprop -id $1 -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 0
    xprop -id $1 -remove _MOTIF_WM_HINTS
}

get_wids() {
    xdotool search --class $1
}

for id in $(get_wids $1); do
    make_wid_desktop_app $id;
done
```

You can use it like this.

```
desktop_terminal terminator-wallpaper
```

It searches for all windows that have the class `terminator-wallpaper` with `xdotools` and change there `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` to `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP` with `xprop`.

Since Openbox does not check if this type was changed after a window was created we need to trick Openbox into doing this.
This gets done by setting the `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS` and removing them.

The same thing can be achieved with `devilspie` when you add

```
(if
   (matches (application_name) "terminator-wallpaper")
   (begin
       (wintype "desktop")
       (undecorate)
   )
)
```

since setting the window to `(undecorate)` is also using the  `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS` trick.

Comment: Looks like we've gotten the last piece of the puzzle! :D

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question correctly then your question is like this: whenever you click on `ToggleShowDesktop` then you want all open application to get minimized except `terminator`.

If this is so then you can achieve this by writing a wrapper script, which will internally call two commands

```
#!/bin/sh
xdotool key "super+d" 
wmctrl -a "terminator"
```

Replace the actual ToggleShowDesktop binary/script by above mentioned wrapper script

It may seem dirty hack but it work.