# Openbox: window on the below layer is inaccessible

Tags: terminal, openbox, wallpaper, devilspie

I am trying to set up a "terminal as desktop wallpaper" in Openbox, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139152/configure-toggleshowdesktop-in-openbox-to-only-act-on-specified-layer)

Openbox has the possibility to set `<layer>below</layer>`, so that window is running as desktop background, and won't be displayed by the statusbar and unaffected by "minimize windows". So instead of displaying a useless image as wallpaper, I actually have a terminal.

The actual terminal that I  am running as background is `terminator`, I have just created a symlink `terminator-wallpaper-1a` and `terminator-wallpaper-1b`, which are just symlinks to the terminator binary. Only so that  the names are different, and I can distinguish them.

I have dual monitor setup, and I want terminator wallpaper on each monitor.

The openbox window property is set by `devilspie`:

```
(if
(matches (application_name) "terminator-wallpaper")
(begin
(wintype "desktop")
)
)
```

And then, I have this in my openbox config, so that each wallpaper goes to corresponding monitor/desktop:

```
<application name="terminator-wallpaper-1a">
  <focus>yes</focus>
  <layer>below</layer>
  <desktop>1</desktop>
  <position>
    <y>0</y>
    <x>0</x>
    <monitor>1</monitor>
  </position>
  <skip_taskbar>yes</skip_taskbar>
  <maximized>true</maximized>
</application>

<application name="terminator-wallpaper-1b">
  <focus>yes</focus>
  <layer>below</layer>
  <desktop>1</desktop>
  <position>
    <y>0</y>
    <x>0</x>
    <monitor>2</monitor>
  </position>
  <skip_taskbar>yes</skip_taskbar>
  <maximized>true</maximized>
</application>
```

Lastly, this is how I start the whole thing:

```
devilspie &
terminator-wallpaper-1a -b &
terminator-wallpaper-1b -b &

xdotool set_desktop 0

xdotool search --class 'Terminator-wallpaper-1a' windowunmap --sync windowmap windowsize %1 1920 1180
xdotool search --class 'Terminator-wallpaper-1b' windowunmap --sync windowmap windowsize %1 1920 1180
```

Everything works nicely, and when I minimize all other windows, I actually see my terminator wallpapers. But only one of them is actually usable. ie, focused, or active. The other I cannot type into. Even when I click with the mouse, the cursors is still inactive, so that the window never becomes focused.

How can I fix this ?

## SOLUTION:

after exhaustive troubleshooting with user @intika, we have identified the problem. Adding following snippet to section `<mouse>` in the openbox config file fixed the issue:

```
<context name="Desktop">
  <mousebind button="Left" action="Press">
    <action name="Focus"/>
    <action name="Raise"/>
  </mousebind>
</context>
```

Comment: I feel issue is `(matches (application_name) "terminator-wallpaper")` which was supposed to be `(matches (application_name) "terminator")` assuming you did not rename binary to terminator-wallpaper. can you confirm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one window/application can have the focus at a time.

In your openbox config both applications/wallpaper have the focus but technically this not possible, so openbox mitigate your configuration by giving focus to only one application (it can not do otherwise).

```
<application name="terminator-wallpaper-1a">
  <focus>yes</focus>
...
<application name="terminator-wallpaper-1b">
  <focus>yes</focus>
```

There are many possibilities to fix this issue, they evolve around implementing a way to switch the focus to the first or second screen desktop/application/wallpaper

**Possible solution 1:**

You may try to set focus value to no or remove the focus line all together, then test switching the focus by a mouse click

**Possible solution 2:**

Use the mouse location to set the focus, here is the [openbox wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:MouseFocusExample) for the matter, first remove the focus entry for both of your wallpaper app then add the following to your openbox config under the main section `<focus></focus>` like described on the linked documentation

```
<followMouse>yes</followMouse>
<!-- move focus to a window when you move the mouse into it -->
```

Note that this will impact your other windows as well...

You can also try to use `followMouse` under the application section but i don't think this is handled by openbox

**Possible solution 2:**

Use xdotool with a keyboard shortcut or else to switch the focus, in fact you can assign a keyboard shortcut a command like the one bellow, also this solution also require you to fix your config by removing/editing the dual  `<focus>yes</focus>`

```
xdotool search --class 'Terminator-wallpaper-1b' windowactivate
```

Same as xdotool, wmctrl can be used for the matter as well:

```
#Lists currently open windows 
wmctrl -l 

#Set focus to windows with title containing STRING
wmctrl -a STRING
```

**Note:**

```
<focus>yes</focus>
# if the window should try be given focus when it appears. if this is set
# to yes it doesn't guarantee the window will be given focus. some
# restrictions may apply, but Openbox will try to
```

**Note 2:**

There are many other possible solutions, you can comment the answer and i will edit it accordingly ;)

Comment: removing `<focus>yes</focus>`, or setting to no does not have any effect. I can make inactive window active with the  `xdotool` command, but then still only one window is "accesible".

Comment: what about the mouse focus solution ? also does a command line linked to a keyboard shortcut suit your needs ?

Comment: the problem here is that the desktop is considered one single layer even if you have 2 screens and thus only one application can have focus on that layer... openbox with `<focus>yes</focus>` is not meant for a dynamic focus on a single layer

Comment: also an other solution could be a python/or/else script that will watch the mouse location + desktop window and set the focus to the proper window... it would require some work but doable in 1 or 2h programming... let me know i'll see what i can do ;)

Comment: also, I should point out, that everything worked fine in earlier versions of openbox (3.5.0). It stopped working with version 3.6.1

Comment: and the solution using `<followMouse>` also does not seem to have any effect. Besides, I need a solution that only affects the layer bellow, not every application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102648/discussion-between-intika-and-martin-vegter).